# Save Image from Remote URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using [Dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) to convert a DIV into a PNG. The div background has an image file from UnSplash. Problem is that the image needs to be on the same server running the script to work. I keep getting the error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Wondering if there is a way I can take an image at a remote url and save it as a file in my assets folder or something?

Comment: Have you considered a server-side option instead?  For example, PhantomJS: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: It's a security feature of javascript.  Without this header present on the destination site, which is probably on a different domain, you are prevented due to ``cross site scripting``: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.  You would need a server side solution to fetch the image or add this header for permission on the other site.

Comment: You can try seeing if you are able to grab the image using a CORS proxy such as https://www.crossorigin.me